# How to replace a string with another

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to make a program that isn't sensitive to the character `,` or `.` as input, in order to make some calculations without thinking about which symbol I should use to separate integer part from fractional part.

The only way  i can imagine is to recognize the input string, check if there's a `.` and replace it with a `,` as my cultureType only accepts  `,`.

The problem is that I don't have any idea to make it, can someone help me?

Comment: please provide your codes you have tried

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to avoid using tag names in your question title.

Comment: What if the number has both , and .? What should it do then

Comment: @JLRishe My guess would be to detect the last occurrence of the character then use that as the decimal delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (yourString.Contains(".")) { youString = yourString.Replace(".", ","); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(inputString.Any(x => x == '.'))
{
    inputString = inputString.Replace('.', ',');
}
```

Comment: This works only if the code accepts input as a string.

Comment: Why use an if to check the input string? Calling Replace directly is faster.

Comment: @Steve Speed schmeed. The more important part is that calling Replace directly is simpler and easier to read.

Comment: I know it but it seems OP wants to check for `dot` first and then replace it.So I added a check too, maybe it's unnecessary but still I don't think that it makes a significant time difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm *guessing* (it's not in your question) that you're trying to parse a decimal, and the number may have a decimal separator and no thousand separator, and it might be a `,` and it might be a `.` A possible heuristic to guess which one it is, is to check the last occurrence of either.

That could be done by

```
string input = "123.456.496,58"; //or 123,456,789.58
int lastComma = input.LastIndexOf(",");
int lastPeriod = input.LastIndexOf('.');

NumberFormatInfo format = new NumberFormatInfo();
if (lastComma > lastPeriod) {
  format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ',';
  format.NumberGroupSeparator = '.';
} else {
  format.NumberDecimalSeparator = '.';
  format.NumberGroupSeparator = ',';
}

double parsed = Double.Parse(intput, format);
```

this fails when there is a group separator after the decimal separator, and other heurisics could be employed to change it (i.e. if there is only one non-numeric character, that one is the decimal separator. If there are multiple non-numeric special characters, and one of them only occurs once, that is the decimal separator)

In the end parsing a string with an unknown format will require some guesswork.

If you're not trying to parse numbers, but are doing something different entirely, disregard this answer, and pick one of the others.

Comment: Ha! Same thing I was doing. Just change your `lastIndexOf`s to `LastIndexOf` and all good.

Comment: thanks, fixed. Working in too many capitalisation conventions messes with me.

Comment: Yeah .NET has the tendency to do that :P

Comment: PascalCase for .NET, camelCase for Scala, snake_case for JS -> use all the wrong conventions all the time!